# verifying points on an elliptic curve

Tags: finite-fields, elliptic-curves

I have an assignment to write a program to verify the points

P = (1+T+T<sup>2</sup>, 1+T), Q = (T<sup>2</sup>,T), and R = (1+T+T<sup>2</sup>, 1+T<sup>2</sup>) are in the field E(F<sub>8</sub>) on the curve:

E:Y<sup>2</sup> +XY+Y = X<sup>3</sup> +TX+(T+1)

on the field:

F <sub>8</sub>= F<sub>2</sub>[T]/(T<sup>3</sup>+T+1)

And I can not for the life of my figure out how to make both sides equal to each other. Ive done the math by hand and with the program but it never comes out right. Can someone please explain how I can verify that these points are on the curve?

Comment: Your program needs to implement the multiplication in the field. For example what is the result of $T^3 T^2$ ?

Comment: I presume you want $Y^2 +XY+Y = X^3 +TX+(T+1)$?

Comment: I get -T^2 + T+1

Comment: $T^3 T^2 = (T+1)T^2 = T^2 + T+1$. Any element of the field has a **unique** expression as $a T^2+bT+c$ with $a,b,c \in \mathbf{F}_2$, that's what such a program needs to implement.

Comment: My book says that when taking the product of two elements im supposed to divide the answer by $T^3+T+T$ and to take the remainder. so $T^3T^2 $ would be $T^5$ and then through polynomial long division i would get $-T^2+T+1$

Comment: In characteristic two you cannot make sign errors. $1=-1$, $T=-T$ et cetera. All because $1+1=0$ and multiplying that equation by anything, say $a$, gives $a+a=0$ and hence $a=-a$.

Answer (score 2):

I presume your $X^2$ should be $X^3$.

I'll just look at $Q$, that's the easy one. Substituting $X=T^2$
and $Y=T$ into
$$Y^2+XY+Y+X^3+TX+T+1$$
gives
$$T^2+T^3+T+T^6+T^3+T+1=T^6+T^2+1=(T^3+T+1)^2=0$$
in $\Bbb F_8$. So $Q$ is on the curve.
 Throughout I am using the fact that $1=-1$ in the field.

Comment: Dont both sides have to be equal to each other instead of all adding together?

Comment: @ErikHatfield We are working in characteristic two: $A=B$ is the same as $A+B=0$ in characteristic two.